# Calling an event in code c#

Tags: c#, wpf, events

Is it possible to call an event such as the one shown below in code.

```
private void Item_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

}
```

The object I want to call it on is ListView.Items[listView.Items.Count-1]

XAML

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" 
            Handler="ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

So my attempt to call it looks like this, but it doesnt work.

```
Item_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(listView.Items[slideListView.Items.Count-1], null);
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: sorry as in the action that would normally happen when this is called doesnt happen.

Comment: Don't manipulate UI elements in code in WPF, please specify what you're trying to do here.

Comment: I havent posted my code which is inside the event

Comment: When a listviewitem is clicked on its content is updated, I just want to make sure that the last items content is updated before a save operation is performed.

Comment: Just move the code that's now inside your event handler into another private method.  Now you can simply call that one.  And that method better not need the MouseButtonEventArgs, you don't have any.

Comment: The code within the event handler is *yours*, if it "doesn't work", fix it.

Comment: I'm giving you +1 here, but not because this is a good question... It's because someone marked you down -1 but didn't bother to tell you why... in my opinion, that is pointless because you aren't learning anything from it. I can only assume that it was because you didn't provide much information in your question, although I could understand it.

Answer (score 5):

It is generally bad practice to call an event handler directly, or to 'fake' an event. Instead of this, why not wrap up the functionality of your handler and put it into another method which the event handler will call. Then, you can call that method from any other location as well.

```
private void PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // Doing something
}
```

=>

```
private DoingSomething()
{
    // Doing something
}

private void PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DoingSomething();
}
```

Now you can call `DoingSomething()` from anywhere.

Comment: Yes, I will probably do this, just wanted to know if there was an easy way just to fire the event. Thanks

Comment: This is what I do for alot of stuff. Like "StartProcess()" that can be called from anywhere, as well as a button-click event handler.